# ng-click not working with chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I created a pie chart with `chartjs`,
but when I click on a specific slice, the click event is not taken.

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsController">
<a>Projects</a>
<br>
</br>
<canvas id="myPieChart" width="600" height="600" ng-click="chartClick()"></canvas>
```

**Controller:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Progs')

.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', '$state',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $window, $state) {
  //...
  $scope.chartClick = function (event) {
    console.log('chartClick');
    //console.log("segment: " + $scope.chart.getSegmentsAtEvent(event));
  }
  //...
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Please note: I am not using `angular-chart.js`

Comment: Can you post what errors you  are getting in console?

Comment: there are no errors in the console, just it does react to the click event

Comment: Please post your whole view, it's not clear whether you've loaded Angular correctly, for example whether you've included `ng-app` or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I studied your problem and be reading ***@MohammadMansoor***'s answer I tried to implement the solution for you.

```js
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("ChartCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = "Hello, World";
    $scope.canvas = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
    $scope.ctx = $scope.canvas.getContext("2d");
    $scope.data = [{
      value: 300,
      color: "#F7464A",
      highlight: "#FF5A5E",
      label: "Red"
    }, {
      value: 50,
      color: "#46BFBD",
      highlight: "#5AD3D1",
      label: "Green"
    }, {
      value: 100,
      color: "#FDB45C",
      highlight: "#FFC870",
      label: "Yellow"
    }];
    $scope.myPieChart = new Chart($scope.ctx).Pie($scope.data,{});
    $scope.chartClick = function (event) {
        console.log('chartClick');
        console.log($scope.myPieChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(event));
    }
    $scope.canvas.onclick = $scope.chartClick;
  }]);
})(angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
  <a>Projects</a>
  <br>
  <canvas id="myPieChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

## here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Slt8jyCPmRozcW1wPTby?p=preview) for the same implementation

Comment: can you please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected

Answer (score 5):

Use html onclick feature and access the scope using any id

### Example:

```
<canvas id="myPieChart" width="600" height="600" onclick="angular.element("#myPieChart").scope().chartClick();"></canvas>
```

Comment: how do u get for instance the label of the slice in such case?

Comment: when I click on each slice of myPieChart, how do I get (in my controller) a reference to the slice I have clicked? If, for instance, I want to get some value of data, having data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    }...,

Comment: You can pass parameters like angular.element("#myPieChart").scope().chartClick('test_arg');   and inside angular fucntion you may get it as normal.Try without single quotes also if it is ot working

Comment: please could u edit your response adding also the  function to use inside the controller? many thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `angular-chart` please use `chart-click = "chartClick"`.

I guess the `chart.js` overrides the click event and doesn't pass it on to angular, so you can't get a `ng-click` event triggered.

You could try binding the click event externally using `angular.element('#myPieChart')` but I am not sure about it.

Comment: You should use it.. it has very handy features... and its a wrapper around chart.js